# Is the graph differentiable when x=-1?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

[image]

The graph is differentiable if I look at it visually. How am I supposed to solve this analytically?

Comment: Why did you decide to equate those two derivatives? What does that have to do with the derivative of $h$ at $x=-1$? Look at the graph.

Comment: For $x\le 0$ and near $x=-1$, the $e^x$ piece is not relevant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is the function $h(x)=\begin{cases} x+1 & x \leq 0 \\ e^x & x>0 \end{cases}$ differentiable when $x=-1$?

Of course, the answer is "yes".

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -1-} h'(x)=\lim_{n \to 0-} \dfrac{h(-1+n)-h(-1)}{n}=\lim_{n \to 0-}\dfrac{n-0}{n}=1, \\ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to -1+}h'(x)= \lim_{n \to 0+} \dfrac{h(-1+n)-h(-1)}{n}=\lim_{n \to 0+} \dfrac{n-0}{n}=1.$

In addition, when $x=0$, It's also diffrentiable, because $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0-} h'(x)=\lim_{n \to 0-} \dfrac{h(n)-h(0)}{n}=\lim_{n \to 0-} \dfrac{n+1-1}{n}=1, \\ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0+} h'(x) = \lim_{n \to 0+} \dfrac{h(n)-h(0)}{n}=\lim_{n \to 0+} \dfrac{e^n-1}{n}=1.$